# How to open PDF file in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, jasper-reports

I have a web application in which I am creating PDF reports using *JasperReport*. I have hosted my website.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String invno=request.getParameter("invno");
        try {
        String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("clDS_Close.jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(absolutePath);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t_fleet","root","aadi");

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        Statement st2=conn.createStatement();

        String queryString = "select tbl_invoice.*,tbl_package.package_name,tbl_package.basic_hr,tbl_package.basic_km,tbl_package.amount from tbl_invoice inner join tbl_package on tbl_invoice.package_id=tbl_package.package_id where tbl_invoice.invoice_no="+invno+"";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        JRResultSetDataSource jasperReports = new JRResultSetDataSource(rset);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null, jasperReports);

        String filename=null;
        filename="CL"+invno+".pdf";

        //Report saved in specified path
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,filename);

        //Report open in Runtime
        String createdFile = getServletContext().getRealPath(filename);
        out.println(createdFile);
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " +filename);
       } catch(Exception e) {
           out.println(e);
       }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

I am accepting invoice number from user and opening PDF file for that invoice.

My problem is my pdf file is getting created and stored to path but, I don't know how to open it. There is a method `RunTime.getRunTime.exec()` in windows. But I think this will not work because as I have hosted my web application to free domain, this method will not work there.
 Please tell me alternative for above method so that I can open my PDF file stored in specific path.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979900/2790364) might get something

Comment: No, I have created my PDF using jasper report. I just want to know how to open it through JSP as I have hosted my application to www.jvmhost.net. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FilProtocolHandler") will not work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use response.sendRedirect().

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

you can use servlet.

```
@WebServlet("/Test.pdf")
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    File file = new File("D:\\Test\\Test.pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type",    getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"Test.pdf\"");
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
   }
}
```

(if Servlet 3.0 is not available, then map it in web.xml the usual way, if Java 7 is not available, then use a read/write loop the usual way)

Just copypaste this class in its entirety into your project and open the desired PDF file by /contextpath/Test.pdf instead of /contextpath/youroriginal.jsp (after having organized it in a package and autocompleted the necessary imports in the class, of course).

E.g. as follows in a JSP where you'd like to show the PDF inline:

```
<object data="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Test.pdf" 
type="application/pdf" width="500" height="300">
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Test.pdf">Download file.pdf</a>
```

Comment: I am messed u with code. Is there any simple way to open PDF file in browser? I have not used servlet at all in web application. So can I do it in JSP?

Comment: try this

'<%@ page import="java.io.File" %><%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils" %><%
File pdfFile = (File) request.getAttribute("pdf");
byte[] pdfByteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(pdfFile);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.getOutputStream().write(pdfByteArray);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
%>'

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Blob"%>
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>View File</title>
</head>
<body>
   <%


String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name";

String user = "username";
String pass = "password";

Connection con = null;
Statement stat= null;
ResultSet rs= null;

PreparedStatement ps=null;
String Filename = "Filename";
Blob file=null;
byte[] filedata = null;

try
{

try
{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, pass);
    stat = con.createStatement();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    out.println("Error During connection to the database : " +e.getMessage());
}
s1="select * from doc where Book_Name='"+Filename+"'";
rs=stat.executeQuery(s1);
try{
    if(rs.next ())
    {
        file=rs.getBlob("Book");
        filedata=file.getBytes(1, (int) file.length());

}


    else
    {
        out.println("file not found.");
        return;

    }
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("content-Disposition","inline");
    response.setContentLength(filedata.length);
    OutputStream output =response.getOutputStream();
    output.write(filedata);
    output.flush();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 out.println("Error while retriving data : " +e.getMessage());     
}

%>

 <%
  }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 out.println("Error in application :"+e.getMessage());
 }

 %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/** @author Taher_JAVAHUNTER*/
public class GeneratePDF {

String logUserId = "0";
public String path = "c:/PDF";

public void genrateCmd(String reqURL, String reqQuery, String folderName, String id) {
    try {
        File destFoldereGP = new File("c:/eGP");
        if (destFoldereGP.exists() == false) {
            destFoldereGP.mkdirs();
        }

        File destFolderPDF = new File("c:/PDF/");
        if (destFolderPDF.exists() == false) {
            destFolderPDF.mkdirs();
        }

        File destFolder = new File("c:/PDF/" + folderName);
        if (destFolder.exists() == false) {
            destFolder.mkdirs();
        }

        File destFolder2 = new File("c:/PDF/" + folderName + "/" + id);
        if (destFolder2.exists() == false) {
            destFolder2.mkdirs();
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("Exception::" + e1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception::" + e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to display jasper reports output in a web page, the cleanest solution is to output the report as HTML, and send the output directly to the browser.

With a little extra work, you can create an interface that allows the user to change sort order and column widths in the UI, and communicates those changes down to the report object for re-rendering.

The second best option is to use the Jasper Report Viewer as an applet in your web page, which allows you to view the reports in native jasper reports format.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest staying away from generating the PDF in a JSP.

Rather generate the PDF VIA an Action and serve the content through a servlet.

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html?page=1

[Display Pdf in browser using java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386233/display-pdf-in-browser-using-java-servlet)

you could potentially as you have access to the HTTP response but this is ugly and shameful

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils" %>
<%
byte[] pdfByteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(pdfFile);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.getOutputStream().write(pdfByteArray);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
%>
```

Exerpt from 
[Displaying pdf in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232916/displaying-pdf-in-jsp)